# Data cleaning and preparation for Time-Series-LSTM

Tags: python, time-series, lstm, data-cleaning

I need to prepare my Data to feed it into an LSTM for predicting the next day. 
My Dataset is a time series in seconds but I have just 3-5 hours a day of Data. (I just have this specific Dataset so can't change it)
I have `Date-Time` and a certain `Value`.
E.g.:

```
datetime..............Value      
2015-03-15 12:00:00...1000

2015-03-15 12:00:01....10

.

.
```

I would like to write a code where I extract e.g. 4 hours and delete the first extracted hour just for specific months (because this data is faulty).
I managed to write a code to extract e.g. 2 hours for `x-Data` (Input) and `y-Data` (Output).
I hope I could explain my problem to you.

The Dataset is 1 Year in seconds Data, 6pm-11pm rest is missing.
In e.g. August-November the first hour is faulty data and needs to be deleted.

```
init = True
for day in np.unique(x_df.index.date):
    temp = x_df.loc[(day + pd.DateOffset(hours=18)):(day + pd.DateOffset(hours=20))]

if len(temp) == 7201:
if init:
    x_df1 = np.array([temp.values])
    init = False
else:
    #print (temp.values.shape)
    x_df1 = np.append(x_df1, np.array([temp.values]), axis=0)
#else:
#if not temp.empty:
    #print (temp.index[0].date(), len(temp))

x_df1 = np.array(x_df1)

print('X-Shape:', x_df1.shape, 
'Y-Shape:', y_df1.shape)
#sample, timesteps and features for LSTM
X-Shape: (32, 7201, 6) Y-Shape: (32, 7201)
```

My expected result is to have a dataset of e.g. 4 hours a day where the first hour in e.g. August, September, and October is deleted.
I would be also very happy if there is someone who can also provide me with a nicer code to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the most efficient solution, but maybe it still fits.

First lets generate some random data for the first 4 months and 5 days per month:

```
import random
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
for month in range(1,5): #First 4 Months
    for day in range(5,10): #5 Days
        hour = random.randint(18,19)
        minute = random.randint(1,59)
        dt = datetime.datetime(2018,month,day,hour,minute,0)
        dti = pd.date_range(dt, periods=60*60*4, freq='S')
        values = [random.randrange(1, 101, 1) for _ in range(len(dti))]
        df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(values, index=dti, columns=['Value']))
```

Now let's define a function to filter the first row per day:

```
def first_value_per_day(df):
    res_df = df.groupby(df.index.date).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[[0]])
    res_df.index = res_df.index.droplevel(0)
    return res_df
```

and print the results:

```
print(first_value_per_day(df))

                     Value
2018-01-05 18:31:00     85
2018-01-06 18:25:00     40
2018-01-07 19:54:00     52
2018-01-08 18:23:00     46
2018-01-09 18:08:00     51
2018-02-05 18:58:00      6
2018-02-06 19:12:00     16
2018-02-07 18:18:00     10
2018-02-08 18:32:00     50
2018-02-09 18:38:00     69
2018-03-05 19:54:00    100
2018-03-06 18:37:00     70
2018-03-07 18:58:00     26
2018-03-08 18:28:00     30
2018-03-09 18:34:00     71
2018-04-05 18:54:00      2
2018-04-06 19:16:00    100
2018-04-07 18:52:00     85
2018-04-08 19:08:00     66
2018-04-09 18:11:00     22
```

So, now we need a list of the specific months, that should be processed, in this case 2 and 3. Now we use the defined function and filter the days for every *selected* month and loop over those to find the indexes of all values inside the first entry per day +1 hour later and drop them:

```
MONTHS_TO_MODIFY = [2,3]
HOURS_TO_DROP = 1

fvpd = first_value_per_day(df)
for m in MONTHS_TO_MODIFY:
    fvpdm = fvpd[fvpd.index.month == m]
    for idx, value in fvpdm.iterrows():
        start_dt = idx
        end_dt = idx + datetime.timedelta(hours=HOURS_TO_DROP)
        index_list = df[(df.index >= start_dt) & (df.index < end_dt)].index.tolist()
        df.drop(index_list, inplace=True)
```

result:

```
print(first_value_per_day(df))

                     Value
2018-01-05 18:31:00     85
2018-01-06 18:25:00     40
2018-01-07 19:54:00     52
2018-01-08 18:23:00     46
2018-01-09 18:08:00     51
2018-02-05 19:58:00      1
2018-02-06 20:12:00     42
2018-02-07 19:18:00     34
2018-02-08 19:32:00     34
2018-02-09 19:38:00     61
2018-03-05 20:54:00     15
2018-03-06 19:37:00     88
2018-03-07 19:58:00     36
2018-03-08 19:28:00     38
2018-03-09 19:34:00     42
2018-04-05 18:54:00      2
2018-04-06 19:16:00    100
2018-04-07 18:52:00     85
2018-04-08 19:08:00     66
2018-04-09 18:11:00     22
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I adapted it a little bit and it worked fine.

Comment: It is nice to hear, I am happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer helped you solving your issue, please mark it as accepted. :-)